# Правильное обновление вложенных в state объектов в Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

Друзья, у меня имеется сложная форма с множеством полей ввода и **state** React-приложения, представляющее из себя объект с полями и **другими вложенными объектами** для хранения и валидации полей данной формы.

Чтобы **не писать уникальную функцию** для обновления значения каждого из полей формы, я написал универсальную функцию **updateField**, которая принимает **путь к обновляемому полю** внутри **state** и **новое значение** для данного поля.

Например, такой вызов

```
updateField("users.1.name", "Vova");
```

Эквивалентен такому коду

```
let state = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state));
state['users']['1']['name'] = "Vova";
this.setState(state);
```

Я прекрасно понимаю, что строчка

> let state = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state));

это плохое решение. И вообще подозреваю, что работать это будет очень медленно.
Очень хотелось бы найти способ обновлять только то поле, которое в этом нуждается, ведь

```
this.setState({field:value})
```

Будет работать гораздо быстрее, чем

```
 let state = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state));
 state['field']= value;
 this.setState(state);
```

**Вопрос:** Как быть? Нашел вот такой инструмент [fastCLone](https://github.com/ivolovikov/fastest-clone), но подозреваю, что нужен не инструмент, а правильный подход.

Comment: нормальные чуваки используют https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik или https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/  . Не теряйте время на собственное изобретение, потратьте время на изучение того, что потом Вам будет огромным плюсом.

Comment: там ещё final-form доехала неск. месяцев назад

Answer (score 0):

Используйте библиотеки вроде https://github.com/planttheidea/unchanged

```
this.setState(set('nested.value', 'newValue', this.state));
```